# I want to retrieve the values from the db using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

> In the view it is getting the error like ***undefined variable categorylist***,can u
>   pls help me !!!!!!!

**Controller**

```
public function categorylist()
{
    $data['categorylist']=$this->userprocessmodel->categorylist();
    $this->load->view('user/home',$data);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function categorylist()
{
    $query=$this->db->get('category');
    echo $query->num_rows();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
       return null;    
    } 
}
```

**view**

```
<?php 
      if($categorylist)
      {
          foreach($categorylist as $categorylist)
          {
               $categorylist->categoryname;
          }
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user/userprocessmodel');
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change these code in **model**

```
public function categorylist()
{
$query=$this->db->get('category');
echo $query->num_rows();
if($query->num_rows()>0)
{
    return $query->result();
}
else
{
   return 0;    
} 
}
```

Now in **controller** if 0 get then

```
public function categorylist()
{
$data['categorylist']=$this->userprocessmodel->categorylist();
if($data['categorylist']=='0')
{
   $datanone['categorylist']='None';
   $this->load->view('user/home',$datanone);
}
else{
 $this->load->view('user/home',$data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view should be like this

```
<?php 
  if(count($categorylist)>0)
  {
      foreach($categorylist as $categorylist)
      {
           $categorylist->categoryname;
      }
  }else{
     echo 'No category found';
  }
```

?>

Also you dont need to echo $query->num_rows()

Comment: View is ok but my category values are not retrieved here, that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you must change:

```
return null;
```

With:

```
return false;
```

If you assign null to variable $categorylist, the variable is not initialized, and you get that error in your view, if you assing false instead, the variable is initialized with the boolean value false.